# Convert list of integers to Unicode C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a list of integers, for example

```
int[] list = { 350,290,10};
```

How do I convert the lits into a Unicode string where items in the list are the characters decimals ? And inversely - Unicode string into a list of decimals.

Comment: Would you like spaces separating the numbers?

Comment: So much vagueness... what does "characters decimals" mean? And what do you mean by a "list of decimal"? A list of the `decimal` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this:

**decimal to unicode string:**

```
int[] list = { 350, 290, 10 };

System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

var result = list.Select(i => encoding.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i))).ToList();
```

Also you can try the inverse idea to go from unicode string to decimal.

Comment: Yes, this works but somehow it adds an empty space after each character.

Comment: @user2816447 you may try this: `var result = list.Select(i => encoding.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(i)).Remove(1, 1)).ToList();`